# All keydown press stops in the keydown event except the tab key

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

In my react project, I have a scenario wherein the keyDown Event gets triggered on all the keyboard events **except the tab event**, when I press the tab it focuses on the next element that's there on the page.

Please check the screenshot.

Could you please advise why the tab press doesn't call the onKeyDown event but it does for any other key press?

Thanks

[Click here to view the gif: Event get triggered on ArrowDown/w or any other keys except Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvAxU.gif)

```html
class CalendarDay extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

  }

  onKeyDown(day, e) {

  //***** DOESN'T GET TRIGGERED ON 'TAB' KEY PRESS

    const { onDayClick, onFoscusedTabKey, onKeyDownTabFocus } = this.props;
    const { key } = e;
    if (key === 'Enter' || key === ' ') {
      onDayClick(day, e);
    } else if (key === 'Tab' && !e.shiftKey) {
      onFoscusedTabKey(e);
    }

    onKeyDownTabFocus && onKeyDownTabFocus(e);
  }
  

  render() {
    const {
      ...
    } = this.props;


    return (
      <td
        role="link" // eslint-disable-line jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-to-interactive-role
        ref={this.setButtonRef}
        aria-label={ariaLabel}
        onMouseEnter={onDayMouseEnterDebouncedCB}
        onMouseLeave={onDayMouseLeaveDebounceCB}
        onMouseUp={(e) => { e.currentTarget.blur(); }}
        onClick={(e) => { this.onDayClick(day, e); }}
        onKeyDown={(e) => { this.onKeyDown(day, e); }}
      >
        {renderDayContents ? renderDayContents(day, modifiers) : day.format('D')}
      </td>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to add some relevant code instead of just a tiny GIF..?

Comment: @AKX I have added the code snippet

Comment: What is the value for `tabIndex`?

Comment: @AKX, The value of tabIndex  will be 0.

Comment: The docs say "Keyboard events are only generated by <inputs>, <textarea> and anything with the contentEditable attribute or with tabindex="-1"."